# How to calculate the minimum kinetic energy required by a surface molecule to escape the liquid (during evaporation)?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, kinetic-theory, evaporation

Evaporation occurs when surface molecules have enough Kinetic Energy to escape the surface of the liquid. Given a certain volume of liquid at a certain temperature, is it possible to determine this value of Kinetic Energy?

Comment: What thoughts do you have about how to do this?

Comment: At this moment, I'm clueless. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: May I ask : What is your motivation?  Why are you trying to find an answer to this question?  Is this part of your studies in Physics or Chemistry?  I am trying to determine what your background is, what level of understanding you have already.  The policy of this website is to help you find an answer, rather than to provide a complete, detailed answer.

Comment: I am a high school student. I recently did an experiment in which I would essentially blow air directly over the surface of hot water. I did this for over 11  values of wind velocity and I found that the cooling rate of water saturates after a certain value of wind velocity. I am wondering how one can derive this theoretically. For this purpose I am first trying to understand evaporation of water and therefore I asked this question.

Comment: Very good.  If you only require a value, rather than a calculation, the latent heat of vaporization might tell you what you need to know.  This is about 41 kJ/mol for water.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization

Comment: I think you are trying to relate your results to macroscopic properties (temperature, latent heat, density and humidity of air, speed of flow of air) rather than microscopic properties used in kinetic theory (speed of molecules, strength of intermolecular forces, mean free path in air, etc).  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to relate.

Comment: May take a few hours for me to provide an answer (if I can)...

Comment: Linked : A theoretical model for evaporation occurring when wind is blowing over the surface of water, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262207

Comment: Possibly useful : Is there an equation to calculate water evaporation taking into account environmental variables? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105807
What is the equation that determines evaporation rate for water? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/205920

Comment: I asked this question :http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262207/a-theoretical-model-for-evaporation-occurring-when-wind-is-blowing-over-the-surf, but apparently it got put on hold.

Comment: What if you use k_B * T as the energy and put T as the boiling point?

Comment: I've never come across this formula. Could you give some reference?